# Passing command line arguments to a function

Tags: c, svm, libsvm

I am using the LIBSVM in C for gender detection. In the sum-train.c there is a function
**parse_command_line(argc, argv, input_file_name, model_file_name);**

Now i want to pass the arguments to this function but not using command line, but within this program. e.g the argument can be:
**-s 1 -t 2 -c 1 -g 0.5 -v 5 input_file_name model_file_name**

But i don't know how to pass these arguments to this function. 
*NOTE: I am doing all this because i don't want to use the binaries provided. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If they're standard `main`-type arguments, here's what you need.

`argc` must be the count of arguments, *including* the "program name" (quoted because what this value is set to is implementation dependent).

`argv` should be an array of character pointers specifying:

- the "program name".
- each argument.
- a NULL terminator.

So, for the command line

```
-s 1 -t 2 -c 1 -g 0.5 -v 5 input_file_name.dat model_file_name.dat
```

you would have:

```
const char *myArgV[] = {
    "progname",
    "-s", "1",
    "-t", "2",
    "-c", "1",
    "-g", "0.5",
    "-v", "5",
    "input_file_name.dat",
    "model_file_name.dat",
    NULL };
int myArgC = sizeof (argv) / sizeof (argv[0]) - 1;
```

and call:

```
char inputfile[100]; // potential buffer overflow risk but, since it is
char modelfile[100]; //  sample code, not really relevant.
parse_command_line (myArgC, myArgV, inputfile, modelfile);
```

This would parse the arguments, populating the two file name variables you passed in, and setting up the internal `svm_parameter` based on the arguments provided.

Comment: But they are already defined inside parse_command_line(). Have a look at the function [link]http://gt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hrl/libsvm3/svm-train.c    I cannot redefine them. Just I want to call this function with these arguments but don't know how to do it. I am not an expert in C.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @wishee77, sorry, perhaps I wasn't too clear. The argc/argv I had was local and you would just pass it in to that function. I'll rename the local ones to make it clearer and show how to call the function.

Comment: thanks alot. I will wait for your reply. I tried to call the function in different ways but its not working. that will be so nice of you if you can help me out. And thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: @wishee77, another misunderstanding, I think :-) I've _already_ updated my answer with the changes. You should re-read it.

Comment: Thanks alot for quick reply. I did the way you said but its giving error: svm-train.c: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
svm-train.c:71: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'  Do you know,why?

Comment: Yes, because your compiler warnings are doing the right thing :-) I've changed myArgV to be _const_ char *. Try again, but be aware I have to nick out for a bit - SO's not meant to be an online person-to-person help system :-)

Comment: Yes, i can understand. Sorry for wasting your time. Can you tell me how to change it to get it working.

Comment: ohhh but i didn't used the const keyword and still am getting errors.

Comment: But still the error:svm-train.c:74: error: invalid conversion from 'const char**' to 'char**'
svm-train.c:74: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void parse_command_line(int, char**, char*, char*)'